# How to replace text based on another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

In my db i have such structure

```
text:
id | text
1  | sample text [[[aaa]]], random text [[[bbb]]] ... [[[zzz]]]]
n  | ...

params:
name | value
aaa  | 111
bbb  | 222
...  | ...
zzz  | 7878778
```

I dont know how many blocks of [[[ ]]]] in each string, so i can't use regexp_replace.
After select i want to get this:

```
text:
    id | text
    1  | sample text 111, random text 222 ... 7878778
    n  | ...
```

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: @MT0 , i'll be glad, if you will help with this :)

Comment: Why don't just remove every square bracket ?

Comment: we know nothing about your Problem. what do you want to achieve exactely? how should the two tables interact? what have you tried?

Comment: REPLACE(REPLACE(col, '[', ''),']',''), First replace opening bracket and then get the new string and replace closing bracket.

Comment: My question:Are these just asked for the fun of it or anywhere do we actually need data operations such as this ?

Comment: nope, stackoverflow.com/questions/45860819/ . it's real task and i'm not so good in sql to do this

Comment: Is it.?. However  Your comment below  -< " nope, plsql denied :( only hardcore, only native sql" > means something else...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
WITH indexed_params ( id, name, value, num_params ) AS (
  SELECT ROWNUM, name, value, COUNT(1) OVER () FROM params
),
replacement ( id, text, idx, num_params ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         REPLACE( text, '[[' || p.name || ']]', p.value ),
         1,
         p.num_params
  FROM   inputs i
         LEFT OUTER JOIN indexed_params p
         ON ( p.index = 1 )
UNION ALL
  SELECT r.id,
         REPLACE( r.text, '[[' || p.name || ']]', p.value ),
         r.idx+1,
         r.num_params
  FROM   replacement r
         INNER JOIN indexed_params p
         ON ( p.index = r.idx+1 )
  WHERE  r.idx < r.num_params
)
SELECT id, text
FROM   replacement
WHERE  idx = num_params;
```

Comment: thank you! with your examples i can do this tasks, have a nice time ;)

Comment: i didn't understand one thing. what means p.index? maybe p.rownum?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a PL/SQL function like this

```
function replace_params (p_string varchar2) return varchar2 is
  l_newstr varchar2(32767) := p_string;
begin
  for r in (select name, value from params) loop
    l_newstr := replace (l_newstr, '[[[' || r.name || ']]]', r.value);
  end loop;
  return l_newstr;
end;
```

Then apply to the text:

```
select replace_params(text) from text;
```

Comment: nope, plsql denied :( only hardcore, only native sql.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this assuming the number of brackets is not always the same. Here is a functional example:

```
create table #Text
(
    _id int, 
    _text nvarchar(500)
) 

Insert Into #Text SELECT 1, 'sample text [[[aaa]]], random text [[[bb]]] ... [[zzz]]'

create table #Params
(
    _name nvarchar(50), 
    _value nvarchar(50)
)

Insert Into #Params SELECT 'aaa', '111'
Insert Into #Params SELECT 'bb', '222'
Insert Into #Params SELECT 'zzz', '999'

Declare @_result nvarchar(500);

Set @_result = (Select _text from #Text WITH (NOLOCK) 
Where _id = 1 )

SELECT @_result;

declare c cursor local for 
Select _name,_value from #Params WITH (NOLOCK)

declare @_name nvarchar(50), @_value nvarchar(50)
open c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @_name, @_value
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 
    BEGIN
    SET @_result = REPLACE(@_result,'['+@_name+']',@_value);
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @_name, @_value
    END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c

SET @_result = REPLACE(REPLACE(@_result,'[',''),']','');

SELECT @_result;

DROP TABLE #Text
DROP TABLE #Params
```

Comment: This appears to be an SQL Server answer - unfortunately, the question is tagged Oracle and this will not answer the question.